# What are some alternatives to Hidden Markov Models for Part of Speech tagging?

Tags: classification, hidden-markov-model

I wanted to build a POS tagger but found the HMM Tagger to be too mainstream. Any other Classifier/Statistical Model that I could use?

Comment: What's wrong with something "mainstream"? That's a very silly reason to reject a fairly well understood graphical model.

Comment: I wanted to build a POS tagger @horaceT and the HMM tagger has been implemented a lot. So I wanted to do something new.

Comment: Have you heard of conditional random fields?

Answer (score 0):

There has been interesting work on POS tagging by Google

> SyntaxNet : 
>   https://research.googleblog.com/2016/05/announcing-syntaxnet-worlds-most.html

You can check their paper here :

> Globally Normalized Transition-Based Neural Networks
>   https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.06042

You can use it directly to train a POS tagger or to get the dependency tree if I remember correctly.